# Problem with real time location updates Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

So I have a Google Maps activity for my app I'm making in Android Studio and i need to get real time location updates. The goal is to make markers on the map only clickable when close enough to them.
This is the code I have at the moment:

```
        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setInterval(5000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(2500);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
                if (locationResult == null) {
                    return;
                }
                mLastKnownLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();
                LatLng lastKnownLatLng = new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude());

//THIS IS AN EXAMPLE OF THE DISTANCE VALUES
                distanceHala = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(lastKnownLatLng, HalA);

                mFusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
            }
        };
        mFusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, null);
```

Later on I have some if statements to make them clickable. The problem is now that the location only updates when I just open the Map activity but not while the activity is running. So when I am out of range when I open the activity and then walk close enough, the button still isn't clickable even if I am close enough.

Comment: When the first callback is invoked, the last statement in the callback is to remove location updates - so it seems to be behaving just as programmed.  Why the `removeLocationUpdates`?

Comment: When I remove that line, I still have the same problem, just tested

Comment: Using emulator or real device?

Comment: I used a real device to test it